# how can i use data agumentation option in yolov5?

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

I want to feed images rotated at 90,30,45 degrees in yolo v5.But I only find one hyperparameter to tune in hyp.scratch.yaml file.

```
degrees:0.0
```

Can I do something like this??

```
degrees:0.1,0.2,0.3
```